# Cakephp Configuration Security

Tags: security, configuration, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP application, which accesses multiple APIs. For these APIs, I store keys and password/ secret in a central configuration file.

Small example..

```
/** 
 * A set of Keys set as environment variables for Security Reasons.
 */
'openweathmapappID' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'googleplaceapikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
```

I load these credentials centrally in app.php file.

```
Configure::load('app', 'default', false);
```

I then use them in my Controllers.

```
$key = Configure::read('openweathmapappID');
$response = $http->get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=' . $key);
```

Now how can I best secure my configuration file? Or is it already sufficiently secure?

Comment: Can we assume that this `app.php` is not saved in your source control repository?

Comment: Hello Greg. It is not visible in my source control repo on GitHub no.. Is this enough?

Comment: It's an important step, for sure. The rest is mostly just good server configuration, I think. The config folder should not be in a place where it can be accessed via HTTP, which is generally true of Cake apps, though it's not hard to set that up wrong. You shouldn't allow anonymous FTP to access that folder. You shouldn't allow SSH access with an easily hackable password. If you've got a CMS, the admin side of that needs to be secured too, or else someone can use that to upload back doors. If it's a shared server, then folder and file permissions are important to have right.

Comment: I'm sure there's many other ways to screw up server security. Those are all going to apply to more than just your API keys, though.

Comment: I'm wondering whether using HTTP instead of HTTPS in your call is a problem. I don't know whether HTTPS secures the headers of the request. Is there any good reason for you not to use HTTPS there?

Comment: Thanks Greg, I am still in the process of development and have already found a number of attack vectors. So I'm kind of in the process of gradually implementing better security. Cake has a Security Plugin which targets form tampering and some other threats. It would be handy to have like a list of things to do before going into production. I am finding out more and more every day.. :-). For sure there are a lot of ways to screw up server security.. :-)